# Avoiding if statement inside a for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, design-patterns

I have a class called `Writer` that has a function `writeVector` like so:

```
void Drawer::writeVector(vector<T> vec, bool index=true)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (index) {
            cout << i << "\t";
        }
        cout << vec[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm trying not to have a duplicate code, while still worrying about the performance.
In the function, I'm doing the `if (index)` check on every round of my `for`-loop, even though the result is always the same.
This is against "worrying about the performance".

I could easily avoid this by placing the check outside of my `for`-loop.
However, I'll get loads of duplicate code:

```
void Drawer::writeVector(...)
{
    if (index) {
        for (...) {
            cout << i << "\t" << vec[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        for (...) {
            cout << vec[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

So these are both "bad" solutions for me.
What I've been thinking, is two private functions, one of them outs the index and then calls the other.
The other one only outs the value.
However, I can't figure out how to use it with my program, I'd still need the `if` check to see which one to call...

According to the problem, polymorphism seems like a correct solution.
But I can't see how should I use it here.
What would be the preferred way to solve this kind of problem?

This is not a real program, **I'm just interested in learning how this kind of problem should be solved.**

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Maybe some people want to learn programming, and are curious on how to solve problems?

Comment: What Jonathon said. And also, remeber that modern branch predictors have gotten pretty good. And your `if` inside the loop would not be hard to predict correctly with high precision.

Comment: I have given this question +1. This kind of optimization may not often be necessary, but firstly, pointing out this fact can be part of the answer, and secondly, rare types of optimization are still highly relevant to programming.

Comment: **The question is about good design which avoids code duplication and complicated logic inside the loop.** It is a good question, no need to downvote it.

Comment: It's an interesting question, usually the loop-transformation passes in the compiler will solve this very efficiently. if the function is sufficiently small like this one the inliner will take care about it and will most likely kill the branch off completely. I'd rather change the code until the inliner is happily inlining the code than solving this with templates.

Comment: The cost of the test and branch is completely overwhelmed by the cost of the `<<`. Furthermore, the test always goes the same way, so the branch predictor will do a fine job. There will be no measurable difference.

Comment: I am surprised that the optimizer doesn't just unswitch this.  Isn't that a standard optimization?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Why can't you guys ***just assume the OP has already profiled his code*** and just answer the darn question? Even if the OP hasn't, whoever sees this question in the future likely has. You're **not doing *anyone* any favors** by dismissing the question with stupid *"Why do you care?"* comments.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm pretty sure `cout` was just an *example*; the OP could easily have said `// [...do work...]` to get the point across, without even writing a single statement. The question is still answerable (and still a good one) even when the example given isn't the best one possible, so there's no reason to dismiss the underlying question just because of the particular example used.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Huh? The first revision of the question is virtually identical to this one. Your "why do you care?" comment is 100% irrelevant to *all* of the revisions. As for reprimanding you publicly -- it's not just you, it's a lot of people here who cause this problem. *When the title is "avoiding if statements inside a for loop"*, **it should be pretty obvious** that the question is generic, and *the example is just for illustration*. You're not helping anyone when you ignore the question and make the OP look stupid because of the particular illustrative example he used.

Comment: You can't just say `[... do work ...]` because the answer is highly dependent on what work you're doing!

Comment: @RaymondChen: Hmm? I don't see how. The techniques required for avoiding `if` inside the loop are exactly the same irrespective of the actual work being done... namely, using templates or passing functors (as shown below). It doesn't matter what the code is actually doing...

Comment: @Mehrdad "Worrying about performance" was the motivation for the question (mentioned twice by the OP). Whether this is worth worrying about depends on what `[...do work...]` does. Practical programming includes not worrying about things that don't matter.

Comment: I try to avoid `bool` function parameters when designing interfaces. They can make the calling code difficult to read. To pick on JsonCpp, consider this example: `Json::Reader r; r.parse(input_string, output_json, false);` There's no clarifying comment and you don't have the documentation handy. **What does the `false` mean?**

Comment: @funroll That's *exactly* why you document your programs, so people wont get confused what does the `false` mean... ;___;

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Pass in the body of the loop as a functor.** It gets inlined at compile-time, no performance penalty.

The idea of passing in what varies is ubiquitous in the C++ Standard Library. It is called the **strategy pattern.**

If you are allowed to use C++11, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template <typename Container, typename Functor, typename Index = std::size_t>
void for_each_indexed(const Container& c, Functor f, Index index = 0) {

    for (const auto& e : c)
        f(index++, e);
}

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    set<char> s{'b', 'a', 'c'};

    // indices starting at 1 instead of 0
    for_each_indexed(s, [](size_t i, char e) { cout<<i<<'\t'<<e<<'\n'; }, 1u);

    cout << "-----" << endl;

    vector<int> v{77, 88, 99};

    // without index
    for_each_indexed(v, [](size_t , int e) { cout<<e<<'\n'; });
}
```

This code is not perfect but you get the idea.

In old C++98 it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct with_index {
  void operator()(ostream& out, vector<int>::size_type i, int e) {
    out << i << '\t' << e << '\n';
  }
};

struct without_index {
  void operator()(ostream& out, vector<int>::size_type i, int e) {
    out << e << '\n';
  }
};


template <typename Func>
void writeVector(const vector<int>& v, Func f) {
  for (vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
    f(cout, i, v[i]);
  }
}

int main() {

  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(77);
  v.push_back(88);
  v.push_back(99);

  writeVector(v, with_index());

  cout << "-----" << endl;

  writeVector(v, without_index());

  return 0;
}
```

Again, the code is far from perfect but it gives you the idea.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<100;i++){cout<<"Thank you!"<<endl;}` :D This is the kind of solution I was looking for, it works like a charm :) You could improve it with few comments (had problems understanding it at first), but I got it so no problem :)

Comment: I am glad it helped! Please check my update with C++11 code, it is less bloated compared to the C++98 version.

Comment: Nitpick: this is fine in OP's example case because the loop body is so small, but if it was bigger (imagine a dozen lines of code instead of just a single `cout << e << "\n";`) there would still be quite some code duplication.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to remove code duplication. My goal was to solve this particular one in a simple way.

Comment: @Ali: Which is why I said I was nitpicking. ;)

Comment: @SkamahOne It turns out your code can be generalized. Please check my updated C++11 example.

Comment: Why are the structures and operator overloading used in the C++03 example? Why not just make two functions and pass the pointers to them?

Comment: @Malcolm Inlining. If they are structures, chances are the function calls can be inlined. If you pass a function pointer, chances are those calls **cannot** be inlined.

Comment: @Ali Inlining. Usually, I use function pointers, but it is important that they are declared const. In this case, gcc can actually inline the calls. But then again, it is safer to use templates, since then the calls are inlined by construction. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @JensMunk I am afraid declaring the function pointers `const` is neither necessary nor sufficient due to `const_cast` and friends... :( The `const` is (basically) just a compile-time check, giving a compile-time error if you violate the const correctness. In other words, the compiler *must already know* whether that function pointer is const or not; you are (usually) not giving new information to the compiler by declaring something const. That's rather disappointing. :( My advice would be to use link-time optimization. Then, the compiler is usually able to do the necessary inlining.

Comment: @JensMunk *"Thanks for the example."* Feel free to upvote the answer if you find the example useful. ;)

Comment: @Ali. I am aware of that - const_cast, friends etc. I have an unfortunately long templated example at work demonstrating how a member function was inlined only after I declared it const. The only explanation I can think of is that the preprocessor takes into account declarations in the decisions about what to inline

Comment: @JensMunk Hmm. Interesting. However, a `const` member function is different from a `const` function pointer. Nevertheless, it is interesting that adding a const changed the inlining behavior. In any case, I can only recommend link-time optimizations; it can lead to substantial speed improvements due to the the better inlining.

Comment: @Ali Agree about link-time optimization. In my particular case, I need to compute profiles for some hardware (5000 lines x 192 channels x 32 depths) and in less than 10 ms. Everything is on stack. Usually, I would have used old-style C using SIMD, but I tried using templates for similar function operating on fixed-length arrays (32,64,192). I should try to make a small example when I find the time

Comment: You're essentially making the original `bool index` a compile-time variable. However, this is cheating. How to solve the problem for the same interface without either of the 'failed' attempts of the OP is the question. You didn't answer that one and your answer is equivalent to his second failed attempt as it duplicates code.

Comment: @Walter I am afraid I don't understand. *"How to solve the problem for the same interface without either of the 'failed' attempts of the OP is the question."* I don't see *"the same interface"* requirement in the question. The OP seems to be happy with the answer as he accepted it; 66 people upvoted, they likely to think it answers the question. *"You didn't answer that one and your answer is equivalent to his second failed attempt as it duplicates code."* Sorry, I don't understand. Where do I duplicate code unnecessarily? I don't see any duplicated or unnecessary code in my answer.

Comment: @Walter As for the duplication: Are you referring to the discussion between syam and me? If you want me to deal with that, then please post a new question, and show us valid, justified use cases, where it is a real issue. Otherwise we are just discussing an imaginary issue.

Comment: If you don't (want to) understand, then let's stop here and now. I was just following your answers, because I really liked your top answer. But here, I much prefer syam's.

Comment: @Walter *"But here, I much prefer syam's."* Sure, I upvoted that answer too. By the way, syam makes a good point in comments: *"I believe every single answer (as of now) has its own merits, we just all have different ways to tackle this hypothetical problem based on the assumptions we make in the first place. :)"* I agree 100%, all 3 answers make good points and are different.

Comment: @Walter Now, I have spent 15-20 minutes trying to understand your first comment. Please don't suggest *"If you don't want to understand"*: I did spend time figuring out what you meant but I failed. :( If you still have questions, I can only repeat myself, *"please post a new question, and show us valid, justified use cases, where it is a real issue"* (whatever *it* is). However, I am tired of fighting over hypothetical problems in comments.

Answer (score 40):

> In the function, I'm doing the if (index) check on every round of my for-loop, even though the result is always the same. This is against "worrying about the performance".

*If* this is indeed the case, the branch predictor will have no problem in predicting the (constant) result. As such, this will only cause a mild overhead for mispredictions in the first few iterations. It's nothing to worry about in terms of performance

In this case I advocate for keeping the test inside the loop for clarity.

Comment: It's just an example, I'm here to learn how should this kind of problem be solved. I'm just curious, not even creating a real program. Should've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: In that case, keep in mind that *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. When programming, *always* focus on code readability and make sure others understand what you are trying to do. Only consider micro-optimizations and various hacks *after profiling your program and identifying hotspots*. You should never consider optimizations without establishing the need for them. Very often, performance problems are not where you expect them to be.

Comment: And in this particular example (ok, understood, this is just an example) it is very likely that the time spent for loop control and if test is nearly invisible beside time spent for IO. This is often an issue with C++ : choosing between readability at the cost of maintenance and (hypothetical) efficiency.

Comment: You're assuming that the code is running on a processor that has branch prediction to begin with.  The majority of systems running C++ don't.  (Although, probably the majority of systems with a useful `std::cout` do)

Comment: @BenVoigt you are right, I hadn't considered that. Though I'd say that's a fair assumption in the context of 'I'm learning about programming'.

Comment: -1. Yes, branch prediction will work well here. Yes, the condition might actually be hoisted outside the loop by the compiler. Yes, POITROAE. But branches within a loop *are* a dangerous thing that *often* has performance impact, and I don't think dismissing those by just saying "branch prediction" is a good advice if someone really cares about performance. The most notable example is that a vectorizing compiler will need [predication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication) to handle this, producing less efficient code than for branch-less loops.

Comment: If someone cares about performance, they need to _measure_. In a loop that writes to cout, it doesn't matter one bit .

Answer (score 35):

To expand on Ali's answer, which is perfectly correct but still duplicates some code (part of the loop body, this is unfortunately hardly avoidable when using the strategy pattern)...

Granted in this particular case the code duplication is not much but there's a way to reduce it even more, which comes in handy **if the function body is bigger than just a few instructions**.

The key is to use the compiler's ability to perform **constant folding / dead code elimination**. We can do that by manually mapping the runtime value of `index` to a compile-time value (easy to do when there are only a limited number of cases -- two in this case) and use a non-type template argument which is known at compile-time:

```
template<bool index = true>
//                  ^^^^^^ note: the default value is now part of the template version
//                         see below to understand why
void writeVector(const vector<int>& vec) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        if (index) { // compile-time constant: this test will always be eliminated
            cout << i << "\t"; // this will only be kept if "index" is true
        }
        cout << vec[i] << "\n";
    }
}

void writeVector(const vector<int>& vec, bool index)
//                                            ^^^^^ note: no more default value, otherwise
//                                            it would clash with the template overload
{
    if (index) // runtime decision
        writeVector<true>(vec);
        //          ^^^^ map it to a compile-time constant
    else
        writeVector<false>(vec);
}
```

This way we end up with compiled code which is equivalent to your second code example (outer `if` / inner `for`) but without duplicating the code ourselves. Now we can make the template version of `writeVector` as complicated as we want, there will always be a single piece of code to maintain.

Note how the template version (which takes a compile-time constant in the form of a non-type template argument) and the non-template version (which takes a runtime variable as a function argument) are overloaded. This allows you to choose the most relevant version depending on your needs, having a rather similar, easy to remember syntax in both cases:

```
writeVector<true>(vec);   // you already know at compile-time which version you want
                          // no need to go through the non-template runtime dispatching

writeVector(vec, index);  // you don't know at compile-time what "index" will be
                          // so you have to use the non-template runtime dispatching

writeVector(vec);         // you can even use your previous syntax using a default argument
                          // it will call the template overload directly
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that you removed the code duplication at the expense of making the logic inside the loop more complicated. I see it neither better nor worse than what I proposed for this particular simple example. **+1 anyways!**

Comment: @Ali: "*making the logic inside the loop more complicated*" care to elaborate? The logic inside the loop is the same as OP's example, and as far as I can tell once compiled it boils down to the same code as yours. I agree that `writeVector` is slightly more complicated though because it needs the runtime->constant mapping. Anyway, as I said this only expands on your answer which I find perfectly correct too. Yours has the additional advantage to allow completely different strategies to be added easily, but it has a cost too. As you say: "*neither better nor worse*", just different choices. :)

Comment: Logic inside the loop: I mean the loop body. Compare yours `if (index) { cout<<i<<"\t"; } cout <<vec[i]<<"\n";` to mine `f(i, v[i]);`. Let's wrap this discussion up by saying that certain duplications can be factored out but it may lead to more complicated code; a more realistic example and more use cases would be needed to see how the duplication can be best factored out. Agreed? :)

Comment: @Ali: ok I get what you mean now (when comparing to your solution I was just thinking in terms of compiled code, my bad). So yeah, we can easily agree that there's no one-size-fits-all solution. ;)

Comment: Glad we finally agree :) By the way, it turns out that you can generalize the OP code (well, yeah, in many ways). See my updated answer.

Comment: I like your proposal because it shows another possible optimization. It is very possible that index could be a template constant from the start. In this case it could be replaced by a runtime constant by the caller of writeVector and writeVector changed to some template. Avoiding any further change to the original code.

Comment: @kriss: Actually my previous solution already allowed that if you called `doWriteVector` directly but I agree the name was unfortunate. I just changed it to have two overloaded `writeVector` functions (one template, the other a regular function) so that the result is more homogeneous. Thanks for the suggestion. ;)

Comment: IMO this is the best answer. +1

Comment: @Mehrdad Except that it doesn't answer the original question *Avoiding if statement inside a for loop?* It does answer how to avoid the performance penalty though. As for the "duplication", a more realistic example with use cases would be needed to see how it is best factored out. As I said before, I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @Ali: Now *you*'re the one nitpicking... I think we can easily agree that OP really meant *avoiding the **runtime cost** of an `if` statement inside a `for` loop*. ;) But anyway, I believe every single answer (as of now) has its own merits, we just all have different ways to tackle this hypothetical problem based on the assumptions we make in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

In most of cases, your code is already good for performance and readability. A good compiler is capable to detect loop invariants and do appropriate optimizations. Consider the following example which is very close to your code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>

void write_vector(int* begin, int* end, bool print_index = false) {
    unsigned index = 0;
    for(int* it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (print_index) {
            std::printf("%d: %d\n", index, *it);
        } else {
            std::printf("%d\n", *it);
        }
        ++index;
    }
}

int my_vector[] = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    write_vector(std::begin(my_vector), std::end(my_vector));
}
```

I am using the following command line to compile it:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Then, let's dump assembly:

```
objdump -d a.out | c++filt > main.s
```

The result assembly of `write_vector` is:

```
00000000004005c0 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)>:
  4005c0:   48 39 f7                cmp    %rsi,%rdi
  4005c3:   41 54                   push   %r12
  4005c5:   49 89 f4                mov    %rsi,%r12
  4005c8:   55                      push   %rbp
  4005c9:   53                      push   %rbx
  4005ca:   48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
  4005cd:   74 25                   je     4005f4 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x34>
  4005cf:   84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
  4005d1:   74 2d                   je     400600 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x40>
  4005d3:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4005d5:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  4005d8:   8b 13                   mov    (%rbx),%edx
  4005da:   89 ee                   mov    %ebp,%esi
  4005dc:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4005de:   bf a4 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006a4,%edi
  4005e3:   48 83 c3 04             add    $0x4,%rbx
  4005e7:   83 c5 01                add    $0x1,%ebp
  4005ea:   e8 81 fe ff ff          callq  400470 <printf@plt>
  4005ef:   49 39 dc                cmp    %rbx,%r12
  4005f2:   75 e4                   jne    4005d8 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x18>
  4005f4:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4005f5:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005f6:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  4005f8:   c3                      retq   
  4005f9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
  400600:   8b 33                   mov    (%rbx),%esi
  400602:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400604:   bf a8 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006a8,%edi
  400609:   48 83 c3 04             add    $0x4,%rbx
  40060d:   e8 5e fe ff ff          callq  400470 <printf@plt>
  400612:   49 39 dc                cmp    %rbx,%r12
  400615:   75 e9                   jne    400600 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x40>
  400617:   eb db                   jmp    4005f4 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x34>
  400619:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

We can see, that at the begging of the function, we check the value and jump to one of two possible loops:

```
  4005cf:   84 d2                   test   %dl,%dl
  4005d1:   74 2d                   je     400600 <write_vector(int*, int*, bool)+0x40>
```

Of course, this only works if a compiler is capable to detect that a condition is actual invariant. Usually, it perfectly works for flags and simple inline functions. But if the condition is "complex", consider using approaches from other answers.