# what kind of language feature is suitable for similar functions with only several different lines?

Tags: c++

I have a programming problem and I thought it for several days, but still without good solutions.

**There are several big, long and similar functions, in which only several lines are different**. For example:

```
    void bigfunc(){
       //blabla..
       double i, j, k;
       double result;

      //only this part is different
      { result=i++; }              //in bigfunc1;
      { result=i*cos(j);}          //in bigfunc2;
      { result=sin(i)*cos(j)*tan(k);}     //in bigfunc3;

      //blabla...
    }
```

The simplest way is copying the bigfunc 3 times and edit the different lines respectively. Obviously, it is not a good idea.

Now, I choose the template function method in c++, which embraces the different lines into several small functions, such as:

```
    < template class F >
     void bigfunc(F& f){

      ...
      f(i,j,k); //call the function.
      ...
    }

      void f1(int i, int j, int k){
          i++; //only use parameter i!
      }  
      void f2(int i, int j, int k){
          i++; j++; //only use parameter i and j!
      }  
      void f3(int i, int j, int k){
          i++; j++; j++;
      }
```

However, we have to unify the prototype of f(int, int, int) to include all input parameters in three different bigfuncs, while in fact, in bigfunc1 for example, only f(int i) is needed indeed. Therefore, this method seems not elegant enough.

I though that if there are some abstract mechanics which can take **a sentence block as a function parameter  or as a template function parameter**. That will be amazing! For example (pseudocode):

```
       < template class Code>
       void bigfunc(Code code){
        //...

         code(); //direct expand the code in place, which will be amazingly beautiful.
        //....
       }

       code1(){
            i++;   //just be care for the variable name, like #include
       }
       ....
```

Are there some other compiler-time abstract mechanics in any language, which can solve such problem elegantly.

By now, I only heard that the D language's static_if perhaps could tackle such situation. For example:

```
      < template class F>
      void bigfunc(F f){

           if( static_if(f) == func1 ) //it is justified at compile-time, not at run-time.
              i++;
           else if ( static_if(f)==func2){
               i++; j++;
           }...
      }
```

sorry for that I don't know D, and it is just for explanation.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: This reminds me of a similar, recent question: [Avoiding if-statement inside a for-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871471/avoiding-if-statement-inside-a-for-loop) Perhaps that helps.

Comment: So based on what you have it seems like instead of passing a few separate variables in as parameters it might be better to pass a function as the argument, most compiled languages will offer some way of doing this, although some, like java, are not as simple as say c, because of how function passing is handled (java needs to use interfaces and what not)

Comment: Is your problem of listing x y and z at the calling site, or at the site of function definition?

Comment: @AaronK, I believe Java is getting lambdas soon. That should ease the whole annoying interface thing.

Comment: @Yakk, the variables are in big funcs and should be passed into the different called small functions, if we use function to encapsulate these different lines.

Comment: Is your problem with the lambda technique (A) passing the variables explicitly into the lambda within `bigfunc`, or (B) having to list all of the variables that the lambda uses as arguments to the lambda, (C) both, (D) neither, or (E) something completely different?

Comment: This is not about templates per-se, and this is *definitly* not about languages other than C++ - please don't just throw tags at questions randomly.

Comment: Something like `auto b = std::bind(f1, std::placeholders::_1);` will allow `b` to be called with any number of arguments, as long as the first one is compatible as an argument to `f1`. For `f2` you'd use `std::bind(f2, _1, _2)` and so on. If you're not using C++11 there are C++03 alternatives in Boost.

Comment: @LucDanton Very interesting application!

Comment: It appears you forgot the PHP and Ruby tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it a few different ways in D. One would be:

```
void bigfunc(string code)(){
   //blabla..
   double i, j, k;
   double result;

  //only this part is different
  mixin(code);

  //blabla...
}

alias bigfunc!"{ result=i++; }" bigfunc1;
alias bigfunc!"{ result=i*cos(j); }" bigfunc2;
alias bigfunc!"{ result=sin(i)*cos(j)*tan(k);}" bigfunc3;
```

This is similar to the C macro way - you pass a string to the template (the first set of arguments are compile-time template args, the second set are regular function arguments) which is then mixed in as code to create the function.

You could also do it with static if easily enough.

```
void bigfunc(int version)(){
   //blabla..
   double i, j, k;
   double result;

    static if(version == 1)
          { result=i++; }
    else static if(version == 2)
// well you get the idea
```

Then you can alias different template arguments to new names just like with the string.

Comment: Oh, my god! the first is exactly the things I what, which cannot be found in other languages! Is the function "mixin" a system call to expand a string to a code (macro) in place? The D language is horriable, beside the static_if.

Comment: mixin() is a special part of the language rather than a function. But yeah that's basically what it does, mixin("code"); is like pasting "code" right there in the function as you compile it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use just a macro:

```
#define CREATE_FUNC(name, code)    \
void name(){                       \
   //blabla..                      \
   int i, j, k;                    \
                                   \
  //only this part is different    \
  code                             \
                                   \
  //blabla...                      \
}

CREATE_FUNC(bigfunc1, { i++; });
CREATE_FUNC(bigfunc2, { i++; j++; });
CREATE_FUNC(bigfunc3, { i++; j++; k++; });
```

Not so beautiful and "c-plus-plussy", however.

Comment: Great! I've tested it. It seems ok. Although lacking the type checking, I  still think it as a candidated method. A beautiful macro application.

Comment: For adding the static type checking, can Haskell solve it elegantly? I've tried it by Haskell, but failed.

Answer (score 2):

The mythical programming language feature you are looking for is called "subroutine":

```
void bigfunc(int variant){
   //blabla..
   double i, j, k;
   double result;

  //only this part is different
  switch (variant) {
  case 0: { result=i++; } break;             //in bigfunc1;
  case 1: { result=i*cos(j);} break;          //in bigfunc2;
  case 2: { result=sin(i)*cos(j)*tan(k);} break;     //in bigfunc3;
  }

  //blabla...
}

void bigfuncA() { bigfunc(0); }
void bigfuncB() { bigfunc(1); } 
void bigfuncC() { bigfunc(2); }
```

Comment: I found this question via the [Lisp] tag, by the way.

Comment: this method is a dynamic (run-time) method, while not a compile-time method.

Comment: @changhaoyan Says who? All this stuff can be inlined. If `bigfunc` is an inline function, it can be incorporated into `bigfuncA`, `bigfuncB` and `bigfuncC`. In each one, the value of `variant` is known at compile time, and so the `switch` can be statically optimized.

Comment: If it can be statically optimized, this method will be great! Simple and direct. Could you give an example to show that on what kind of situation, it can be optimized exactly as compile-time method. I am not sure for it, and I hunger for the speed. Otherwise, I prefer to the macro method, although it has drawbacks too.

Comment: That depends on your compiler. I use GCC mostly. I would just write the code as above, declaring `bigfunc` as `inline`, compile it and then look at the assembly with `objdump -S <objfile>`. The key situations in the code are that `variant` is known at compile time because it's a hard coded argument in the `bigfunc(0)` call and the two others. So the compiler knows that the parameter can have no other value, and that can propagate right down to the selection statements inside the inline function. The unused cases in the `switch` are in fact provably dead code.

Comment: Great! How about the bigfunc has extra parameters? For example, bigfunc(int variant, double in1,double& out1). Can the switch code be optimized? This is the real situation.

Comment: @changhaoyan I don't see any reason why the other parameters would interfere. It's a compiler quality issue; all I can say is try it. It's good to do "the obvious" and see how well it is translated, and then switch to the preprocessor hacks or C++ approaches if it's not satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure this is what you're after, but function objects may do the trick.

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void bigfunc(Func f, Args... args) {
  //blahblah
  f(args...);
  //blahblah
}

struct f1 {
    void operator()(int& i) {
        ++i;
    }
};

struct f2 {
    void operator()(int& i, int& j) {
        f1()(i);
        ++j;
    }
};

struct f3 {
    void operator()(int& i, int& j, int& k) {
        f2()(i, j);
        ++k;
    }
};

//main...
int i, j, k;
//...
bigfunc(f3(), i, j, k);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the 'common code' inside an inline function which will then be called by all three functions?

Comment: the big func will be divided into two parts, or more parts.

Comment: Maybe you can use an Array int index[2] instead of 3 different pointers and add a parameter to your function which will tell you how many items to change. Then use a for loop... It will be a bit slower, though!

Comment: any dynamic method (run time) is not prefer to, for speed consideration.

Comment: Then, I can't think of anything else than using one (or two) inline functions in C++ for the common code...

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to solve by writing a single higher order function (HOF), which is a paradigm from functional programming.  One common use case is opening a file, doing something with it, then closing it again.  The traditional and error-prone way is to do this manually.  HOFs provide an elegant alternative:

```
void *withFile(const char *fp, const char *mode, void *(*k)(FILE *)) {
    FILE *fh;
    void *result;

    fh = fopen(fp, mode);
    if (fh == NULL) return NULL;
    result = k(fh);
    fclose(fh);
    return result;
}
```

Now you can write several small functions that only deal with the actual file reading.  The withFile procedure makes sure that the file is always closed.  For a more in-depth explanation of this paradigm, you can read [my old blog article](http://ertes.de/techblog/2009-02-19-1-continuations-for-secure-code.html).

Note that the user function does not care if it is passed extra arguments.  Just ignore the extra arguments in the user function.

Comment: Why is there a pure C answer on a C++ question?

Comment: " The traditional and error-prone way is to do this manually." -- Have you ever written any C++ code?

Comment: HOFs are only really HOFs, when you have lexical scope. A proper functional argument is not just a pointer to code; it's a pointer to code plus an environment for resolving the otherwise free variable references made by that code. At the very least you need "downward funargs". Without that, the function pointer introduces as many problems as it solves. Okay, you got the code to be book-ended by a file opening/closing epilog and prolog, but the code doesn't carry any context to do its job.

Comment: Plus, in actual C++ code, this would be dangerous because `k` could throw an exception, causing a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Your first template approach doesn't look too horrible, and unless profiling proves otherwise chances are that the compiler will optimize away the unneeded functions and unused variables, especially if you don't give them names in the declaration of f1 and f2.

But in order to generalize things you need to take a step back and think about the what you actually want to do in an abstract way and not about how you have done it in the concrete case. What do i,j,k actually mean? You have a set of counter variables, and at one point in your bigfunction you want to increase all of them:

```
template <int N>
struct Counting_Variables;

template <>
struct Counting_Variables<1> {
    int i;
};

template <>
struct Counting_Variables<2> {
    int i, j;
};

template <>
struct Counting_Variables<3> {
    int i,j,k;
};

void increase_counters ( Counting_Variables<1> & arguments ) {
    ++(arguments.i);
}

void increase_counters ( Counting_Variables<2> & arguments ) {
    ++(arguments.i);
    ++(arguments.j);
}

void increase_counters ( Counting_Variables<3> & arguments ) {
    ++(arguments.i);
    ++(arguments.j);
    ++(arguments.k);
}

void bigfunction () {
    // Enter appropriate number of counter variables as template argument here:
    Counting_Variables<2> counters;

    // Be lazy and introduce shortcuts for counters.i etc.
    int & i = counters.i;
    int & j = counters.j;


    // do some stuff here

    // increase all the counters
    increase_counters( counters );

    // do more stuff here
};
```

I am guilty as charged, making the Counting_Variables a template is not strictly necessary. Calling them Counting_Variables_with_i_and_j instead of N=2 has the same effect.