# c++: evaluation of an "if" statement in a lambda function

Tags: c++11, lambda

Suppose I have the following snippet of code:

```
bool flag = true;

auto myFunction = [](int a, int b, bool flag)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            // do something with a and b
        }
    }
```

Later in the code, I call `myFunction` thousands of times in a loop, *for the same value of* `flag`.

Then, I have another loop that also calls `myFunction` thousands of times, but for a different value of `flag`.

My understanding is that, being a lambda function, it is an inline function and thus will be repeated wherever it is called.

My question is: will the compiler evaluate the `if` statement *before* "copying" the inline function, and thus not have to perform that check at every single iteration?

Disclaimers:

1. I know that this may fall under the category of micro-optimization, but I would like an answer nonetheless.
2. My example is silly; I could just put the `if` statements outside the loops. But this is just meant to be a representative example of a much more complicated case.
3. My use of lambda functions is inspired from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871471/avoiding-if-statement-inside-a-for-loop) question.

Thanks!

Comment: If you compiler is smart enough to inline the lambda and capable of moving branch out of the loop - there is nothing that will prevent it from doing the both optimizations, but there is no guarantee (I recently seen MSVC stop chaining optimizations at some depth, though branch prediction will save you in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: will the compiler evaluate the if statement before "copying" the inline function, and thus not have to perform that check at every single iteration?

The language does not require it. An optimizing compiler might be able pull that off if it knows the value of `flag` at compile time. However, it's hard telling without looking at the assembly code generated by the compiler.